# Выборка соответствующих записей MySQL

Tags: mysql

Таблица:

`+-----+----------+---------------+
| id  | category | ad_price      |
+-----+----------+---------------+
| 309 |        0 | 500-700 AZN   |
| 310 |        0 | 300-500 AZN   |
| 311 |        0 | 500 AZN       |
| 312 |        0 | 300-500 AZN   |
| 313 |        0 | 1000-1500 AZN |
+-----+----------+---------------+`

Нужно выбрать записи по ad_price >= 600
То есть должны получить id: 309, 313

Comment: Нормализуйте структуру, разнесите "от" и "до" в два разных поля, денежную единицу в третий - и задача станет элементарной.

Comment: @Akina Я это понимаю. Просто у заказчика уже такая таблица. Буду объяснять что так не делается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ad_price, ' ', 1), '-', -1) >= 600
```